# Can't solve this html generating puzzle

Tags: c#, html, algorithm

I have a `Tree` on which I perform a `depth-first` algorithm. It creates a `list` of the Tree in the order of which the elements should come in the HTML.

I use this to `generate the HTML` to be displayed on the view. (each element that is a question has 2 elements, an answer has none; answer is the `leaf`; question the `branch`)

```
var html = "<ul>";

    foreach (var c in listWithElements)
    {
        html += "<li>";
        if (c is Question)
        {
            var v = (Question)c;
            html += v.Content + "<ul>";
        }
        else
        {
            var t = (Answer)c;
            html += t.Content + "</li>";
        }
    }
return html + "</ul>";
```

This generates a perfect structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>QUESTION
        <ul>
            <li>QUESTION
                <ul>
                    <li>ANSWER</li>
                    <li>ANSWER</li>
              **</ul>**
            <li>QUESTION
                <ul>
                    <li>ANSWER</li>
                    <li>QUESTION
                        <ul>
                            <li>QUESTION
                                <ul>
                                    <li>ANSWER</li>
                                    <li>ANSWER</li>
                              **</ul>**
                            <li>ANSWER</li>
                      **</ul>**   
                    </li>
              **</ul>**
            </li>
      **</ul>**
    </li>
    <li>ANSWER</li>
</ul>
```

Except the HTML generation part does not create the **ul** closing tags. It's not that I haven't tried, it's just I can't seem to find a pattern to determine when/where to insert them. I've temporarily added the closing tags to make it more clear where they should be put.

The only pattern I could find was: the  tag should be put after the second DIRECT li child's closing tag of an ul.

Any help?

Comment: If you care anything about performance or efficiency, use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenation.

Comment: You should place closing ul tag after pop up from rendering sub-tree, however your code does not support that type of tracking for now, you should organize this for e.g. through recursion or using stack-like structure to storing these labels

Comment: as I and @jcharlzworth mention, you can do that, just adopting your's DFS for printing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this: (I've tested it in fiddle sample and it seems to be working great)

```
var html = "<ul>";
var stack = [];
var pointer = 0;
stack.push(0);
    foreach (var c in listWithElements)
    {
      while (stack[pointer]==2&& pointer>0){
        html += "</ul>";
        stack.pop();
        pointer--;
      }
        stack[pointer]++;
        html += "<li>";
        if (c is Question)
        {
            stack.push(0);
            pointer++;
            var v = (Question)c;
            html += v.Content + "<ul>";

        }
        else
        {
            var t = (Answer)c;
            html += t.Content + "</li>";

        }
    }
return html + "</ul>";
```

working fiddle example - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70z3z7o5/22/)

edit: This solution is for JS, but it is same in C# with lists:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Console.WriteLine("<ul>");
    string[] listWithElements = { "q", "a", "a", "q", "a", "q", "a", "a", "q" };

    List<int> stack = new List<int>();

    stack.Add(0);
    foreach (var c in listWithElements)
    {

        while (stack[stack.Count() - 1] == 2 && stack.Count() > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("</ul>");
            stack.RemoveAt(stack.Count() - 1);
        }

        stack[stack.Count() - 1]++;

        Console.WriteLine("<li>");
        if (listWithElements[stack.Count() - 1] == "q")
        {
            stack.Add(0);
            Console.WriteLine("qqq");
            Console.WriteLine("<ul>");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("aaa");
            Console.WriteLine("</li>");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("</ul>");

}
```

Comment: This won't pick up that "</ul>" at the end in between two Answer classes

Comment: Yes you right, I thought there must be a question. No need to down vote.

Comment: I cancelled my downvote when you changed your answer, I just didn't want him to spend ages debugging something that wouldn't have worked sorry.

Comment: It still isn't right though, you need to change stack[pointer] == 3 not 2.  He has three levels of nesting in his example.

Comment: why 3? he said that a 'question' has 2 elements, answer has none. So the max is 2 elements in each "node", no?

Comment: Oh sorry...I misunderstood what your code was doing, 2 is right then

Comment: To the person(s) who down vote--> care to explain why you down vote? this works great.

Comment: @ZivWeissman this solution is not in C# :) and it doesn't maintainable, adopted DFS on original tree would be much better than recovery of dropped information by special rule.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  You need more information about each node.  For example, if you look at this bit:

> ```
> > <ul>
> >                                     <li>ANSWER</li>
> >                                     <li>ANSWER</li>
> >                               **</ul>**
> >                             <li>ANSWER</li>
> ```

There is no way for your code to "know" there should be a "**/ul**" there.  It simply isn't given enough information by looping through.  You would need to have some kind of marker on the Answer object that says "this is the last answer in the current group" or something.

Comment: Your answer opened up a nice viewpoint. I've just accepted the other one because it has a complete applicable answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It would be pretty simple with depthfirst search. If you step one step deeper (away from the root) print the opening tag and the content of the node you are now at. If you go one step out (to the root) print the closing tag for the node before doing the step. Just leave out the step with converting the tree into a list and things get pretty simple.

```
define node: {string content}
define question: node AND {node right , node left}
define answer: node

define toHTML:
input: node root
output: string html

list visited
stack stack

push(stack , root)
add(visited , root)

while ! isEmpty(stack)
     node n = first(stack)

     add(visited , n)    
     append(getContent(n))

     if isAnswer(n)
          remove(stack , n)
     else
          question q = (question) n

          if contains(visited , q.left)
               if contains(visited , q.right)
                     pop(stack)
                     append(html , closingTag(q))//append the closingtag of the question
               else
                     push(stack , q.right)
          else
               push(stack , q.left)
```